# Cut an arabic string

Tags: php

I have a string in the arabic language like:

```
على احمد يوسف
```

Now I need to cut this string and output it like:

```
...على احمد يو
```

I tried this function:

```
function short_name($str, $limit) {
    if ($limit < 3) {
        $limit = 3;
    }

    if (strlen($str) > $limit) {
        if (preg_match('/\p{Arabic}/u', $str)) {
            return substr($str, 0, $limit - 3) . '...';
        }
        else {
            return '...'.substr($str, 0, $limit - 3);
        }
    }
    else {
        return $str;
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes it displays a symbol like this at the end of the string:

```
...�على احمد يو
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol displayed after the cut is the result of `substr()` cutting in the middle of a character, resulting in an invalid character.

You need to use [Multibyte String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) to handle arabic strings, such as [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) and [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

You also need to make sure the internal encoding for those functions is set to `UTF-8`. You can set this globally at the top of your script:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Which leads to this:

- `strlen('على احمد يوسف')` returns 24, the size in octets
- `mb_strlen('على احمد يوسف')` returns 13, the size in characters

Note that `mb_strlen('على احمد يوسف')` would also return 24 if the internal encoding was still set to the default `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: But some time we use English alphabet

Comment: @Thirty5Seconds The point of UTF-8 is to work regardless of which alphabet is used. Multibyte functions will work on english too.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

```
return '...'.mb_substr($str, 0, $limit - 3, "UTF-8"); // UTF-8 is optional
```

**Background:**

In ISO 8859-1 Arabic is *not* a **8**-bit character set. The `substr()` calls the internal libc functions which work on sets of 8-bit chars. To display characters higher then 255 (Arabic, Cyclic, Korean, etc..) there are more bits needed to display that character, for example 16 or sometimes even 32-bits. You subtract 3*8-bits which will result in some undisplayable character in UTF-8. Especially if you're going to use a lot of multibyte strings, make sure you use the correct string functions such as `mb_strlen()`

Comment: There are 8-bit character sets for the Arabic alphabet, e. g., Windows-1256 or ISO-8859-6.

Comment: @Gumbo ISO-8859-1 is the default on most systems. If he would be using another encoding then there might not have been a problem in the first place.

Comment: Your statement is still wrong/misleading. Instead you should state that in UCS, the Arabic alphabet is not within the first 128 characters, which are the only characters that are encoded with a single byte in UTF-8.

Comment: But some time we use English alphabet

Comment: Multibyte functions do also work with single byte strings

Answer (score 0):

Try this function;

```
 public static function shorten_arabic_text($text, $lenght)
        {
            mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
            $out = mb_strlen($text) > $lenght ? mb_substr($text, 0, $lenght) . " ..." : $text;
            return $out;
        }
```