# Why trim() affects on the other characters?

Tags: php, trim

The result of [this code](https://3v4l.org/AKRag):

```
echo trim('سلام؟', '؟');
```

Is `�لام`.

Why? I don't even know what's `�` supposed to be. Where does that come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multibyte trim in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066647/multibyte-trim-in-php)

Comment: [cut arabic string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32680409/6521116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because it is right-toleft- language, You can use [**`rtrim()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

[**phpFiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ijir-2xgy) - Hit "Run F9" to execute

```
echo rtrim('سلام؟', '؟');
```

Comment: we don't have question mark before the word in rtl language, so `؟سلام` is not a "valid" anyways

Comment: ha ha ha ... you are right .. but it would be much better if I can check it too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rtrim()`.

This will remove white space from end of the string.

`echo rtrim('سلام؟', '؟');`

And your problem solved..

Answer (score 0):

Your string char is arabic, which is in the reverse order. So you have to use rtrim().

Answer (score 0):

[`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.rtrim.php) is to replace from the right side of the string and it is OK for OP's requirement. But I think `str_replace()` is more appropriate. Trim can be done by it, also helpful to replace from any position of string. An example:

```
$search = ['؟', ' ',]; // Add more elements if required
$str = 'سلام؟';
$output = str_replace($search, '', $str);

echo $output;
```

**Output:**

```
سلام
```