# php built in functions don't work with arabic language

Tags: php, unicode, arabic-support

Ihave problem in php built in functions
it don't work with arabic language
and print only  question mark 
after I count it it like string length Multiply 2  I don't know why
ex: in my code I type name of 5 characters and with `strlen()` print 10
I type name of 5  characters and with `strrev()` print 10 question mark

```
<?php

// variable in Arabic  
 $str = "مصطفى"; 

$str2 = strrev($str);
 
$str_len = strlen($str);

echo $str     . "<br>";
echo $str2    . "<br>";
echo $str_len . "<br>";

?>
```

output  in browser

```
مصطفى 
??????????
10
```

I fix the `strlen()`  via  `utf8_decode` I brought it from php manual

and I  it like this

```
<?php

// variable in Arabic  
 $str = "مصطفى"; 

$str2 = strrev(utf8_decode($str));
 
$str_len = strlen(utf8_decode($str));

echo $str     . "<br>";
echo $str2    . "<br>";
echo $str_len . "<br>";

?>
```

here is the output

```
 مصطفى 
 ?????
 5
```

it's worked but don't fix all the problem  
the others like  strrev() still print  ????? but this time in the same number of characters not Multiply 2

I try to fix it with HTML `<meta charset="UTF-8">` but it didn't work

- I write in `UTF-8` in visual studio code
- I use 7.4.13 version of php

the arabic characters  work with `if` `else` `echo` `for` `while`...... without any problem so is there any solotion or it's from the php language it self ?

- its my first question and may not be understandable or I use this website incorrectly and it have closed once so please don't close it again

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680409/cut-an-arabic-string) might help - [multibyte string functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php)

Comment: And [this](https://kvz.io/reverse-a-multibyte-string-in-php.html) is also worth a look

Comment: @RiggsFolly reversing a UTF8 string is not that simple once you have to start considering that a single glyph might be represented by more than one UTF8 codepoint. Eg: accents/combining marks, of which arabic seems to have a few.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks for the info, in my ignorance the code I linked to worked  for the example given

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to reverse this string? Are you trying to force left-to-right display for arabic text?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes it's worth alot  thank you for helping  with this

Comment: @Sammitch  first the  [link](https://kvz.io/reverse-a-multibyte-string-in-php.html) is works  perfectully second I am learning php and I want to learn how to reverse string in my native language wich is arabic  thank you for your comment and your info

Comment: @RegnerShelby it "works" until it hits a "combining sequence" which is basically 2 or more codepoints that display together as a single visual glyph. When this happens the above-linked code will combine them incorrectly. There are several combining marks in the arabic plane of unicode that seem to be related to numbers, but I don't know how to construct an example case since I don't know the language. See u0600-u0605 in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode#Compact_table).